# Why template functions do not show up in the LLVM-IR?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Why template functions do not show in the LLVM-IR if the function is not called, when emitting LLVM IR from a c++ code,
unlike other types of functions (int, float...) which will be present in the llvm ir 
example: the following function `func1` doesnt show in llvm ir

```
template <class tmp>
tmp func1 () {
    // ...
}
```

---

But this function `func2` always shows in llvm ir

```
int func2 () {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is not a *template function*. This is a *function template*. It is not a function, but a blueprint of a future function. It is completely immaterial. `func<int>` would be a *template function*, i.e. a *function template* with all template parameters already known. This *instantiates* the template, making it to "materialize".

Answer (score 5):

This is because your templates are not functions: they are function templates. They are not compiled until it is instantiated with arguments. For example, take this code:

```
template<typename T>
T foo() { /* ... */ }
```

That will nor output any code.

But this on the other hand:

```
template<typename T>
T foo() { /* ... */ }

int test() {
    return foo<int>();
}
```

Will output the code for both `test` and `foo<int>`.

You can also manually instantiate a template like this:

```
template int foo<int>();
```

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with [how C++ templates work](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates). Since the compiler doesn’t know what `tmp` is until you call the function (or more precisely, when you instantiate it), it doesn’t know how to write code for it. For example, consider this template:

```
template <typename T>
T add(T left, T right) {
    return left + right;
}
```

If `T` is an integer, then the function body is an integer add. If `T`'s a double, it’s a floating-point add. If `T`’s a `std::string`, it’s a function call to `std::string::operator+`.

Since there are a lot of types in any C++ program, and many of them can be added, and pretty much every one is added in different ways, it cannot create the code for the function until it knows this type. If it tried to do it for all possible types `T`, you’d get a combinatorial explosion of possible implementations, almost all of which are never used. Your compile time and binary size would be huge for little if any benefit.

---

Things get slightly more complicated with [class templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template). An instantiation of a class template doesn’t actually need to instantiate all the functions if they aren’t called. Going back to our example, if we instead wrote:

```
template <typename T>
class Adder {
    T add(T left, T right) {
        return left + right;
    }
};

Adder<int> a;
```

this *still* wouldn’t instantiate `Adder<int>::add` even though the compiler has all the information to know that `add<int>` is potentially interesting, because you don’t *actually* call or otherwise instantiate it.